# How can I run a "cron script" on heroku by user interaction on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I have the following script which runs once a day on cron on heroku.

However, I realize that I would like the option for the user to be able to press a button from a web page to initiate this same process.

Is there a way to create a 'subroutine' that either cron can call or from a web request?  I don't want to use a separate service that runs jobs.

I've just put a snippet to illustrate.....

```
letter_todos = Todo.current_date_lte(Date.today).asset_is("Letter").done_date_null

  unless letter_todos.blank? #check if there any ToDos

   # group by asset_id so that each batch is specific to the asset_id
   letter_todos.group_by(&:asset_id).each do |asset_id, letter_todos|
   #  pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:margin => 100) #format the PDF document
       html_file = ''
       letter_todos.each do |todo| #loop through all Letter_Todos

         contact = Contact.find(todo.contact_id) #get associated contact
         letter = Letter.find(todo.asset_id) #get associated Letter 

         redcloth_contact_letter = RedCloth.new(letter.substituted_message(contact, [])).to_html

         html_file = html_file + redcloth_contact_letter
         html_file = html_file + "<p style='display: none; page-break-after: always'><center> ... </center> </p>"

       end 

       kit = PDFKit.new(html_file)
       kit.stylesheets << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets/compiled/pdf.css" 
       file = kit.to_pdf

       letter = Letter.find(asset_id)
       #OutboundMailer.deliver_pdf_email(file)
       kit.to_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/PDF-#{letter.title}-#{Date.today}.pdf")

       # Create new BatchPrint record

       batch = BatchPrint.new
       batch.pdf = File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/PDF-#{letter.title}-#{Date.today}.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by putting the function in question in a file in lib (lib/tasks_n_stuff.rb, say):

```
module TasksNStuff
    def self.do_something
        # ...doing something...
    end
end
```

Then I can call if from a Rake task:

```
desc 'Make sure we depend on :environment, so we can get to the Railsy stuff...'
task :do_something => :environment do
    TasksNStuff.do_something
end
```

Or from a controller (or anywhere, really):

```
class WhateverController < ApplicationController
    def do_something
        TasksNStuff.do_something
    end
end
```

And since you can run a rake task as a cron job (`cd /my/rails/root; rake do_something`), that should be all you need.  Cheers!

Comment: I see so can I put rake do_something in my cron.rake file?

Comment: @Angela  Sounds like a good place to declare a task you'll mostly be calling through cron.  You could put it anywhere that Rake could find it, though, technically.

Comment: @Xavier, Hi, I'm still not exactly clear what to do with the section after "Then I can call if from a Rake task" -- where does that go, does that go in environment.rb?  If I call it from cron, do I just have TasksNStuff.do_something in the cron.rake file?  thanks...

Comment: Hi, I right now to develop a task for cron just write it as do_task.rb and then I am testing it in console as load 'do_task.rb' -- I'd like to leverage this structure somehow I guess....

Comment: @Angela  I defined my rake task (the bit with `desc` and `task`) in lib/tasks/email.rake (mine does e-mail stuff).  I can test it from the console using rake: `rake do_something`  If you're using a ruby script instead of a rake task, you might want to look into using script/runner to run it instead of rake (something along the lines of `script/runner path/to/do_task.rb`).  You won't need anything but the `TasksNStuff.do_something` line if you go that route.  Should work with `load 'do_task.rb'`, too.  And let me know if I'm not being clear and I'll clean up my answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @thank you -- it looks like when I write it as a module I can type TasksNStuff.do_something and it runs the script.  I assume that if I put that into a cron script it will run.  Hmmmthanks, I think that helps, I just don't know what a rake task is exactly...